# Drop down menu fields in ArcMap shapefile

Tags: gis, arcgis, dropdown, shapefile, qgis

I need to create shape file in ArcMap that have drop down field with predefined variables (some of them had 3 variables, some have more than five).

Is it posible to create that type of shapefile?

This need's to me to prevent different user to input different type of information about ownership of companies, type, structure, material. So if I don't have predefined variables in the fields they will put different text. ex. material=wood, some will put "WOOD", "Wood", "Wod" and etc.

Comment: I think ArcGIS Desktop questions are best researched/asked at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is a *coded domain*, where you store `1` in the attribute and there's a domain table that informs the application that `1 = wood`.

A shapefile doesn't have the ability to handle coded domains.

However, [a geodatabase does](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-domain.htm). Try that instead of a shapefile!

Comment: Thank you,  but geodatabase isn't supported in software that used my collegues. I need to make in shapefile or like this one, I made excel table with unique Atributes and they copy from there, but that is temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in another answer to this question, your best bet is to create a file geodatabase (.gdb) with the data you're working with using Export from the ArcMap menu and on doing so, right-click and select **Properties** to add new values that you want to be the only available options for users of your map or application.

See the link below in the ArcGIS resources for more information about domains and how to code the values you want.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/creating-new-attribute-domains-creating-a-new-code.htm